# Lovecraft's Cthulhu Mythos in pre-CoC D&D?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming, cthulhu-mythos

I'm interested in the appearances of elements of H.P. Lovecraft's Cthulhu Mythos in D&D previous to the publication of Call of Cthulhu in 1981. Is there a comprehensive, detailed list available for those appearances?

Answer (score 7):

There's a post on the **Zenopus Archives** titled [**The Cthulhu Mythos in D&D in the 1970s**](http://zenopusarchives.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/the-cthulhu-mythos-in-d-in-1970s.html) which presents a very detailed and reliable-looking *"chronology of early references to the Cthulhu Mythos in Dungeons & Dragons"*.

**Highlights include:**

- The first mention of Cthulhu seems to have appeared in *Feb 1975*, in
  a certain *Greyhawk Supplement* by Gygax and Kuntz.
- In Feb 1978 an article titled *Lovecraftian Mythos in D&D* by Holmes
  and Kuntz appears in *The Dragon* #12.
- In April 1980, in a column titled *Giants in the Earth* in *The
  Dragon* #36, Lawrence Schick and Tom Moldvay include an entry for
  "H.P. Lovecraft's Richard Upton Pickman (King of the Ghouls)"
- Then, finally, in Aug 1980, *Deities & Demigods*, an AD&D hardcover
  rulebook deals with the Cthulhu Mythos, on pages 44-48.

For additional details and more, intriguing entries of the Mythos' unspeakable D&D history, do [read the article on **Zenopus Archives**](http://zenopusarchives.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/the-cthulhu-mythos-in-d-in-1970s.html).

Disclaimer: I'm in no way affiliated with Zenopus Archives. Am just rather thankful to them for their work on this topic. :)

Answer (score -3):

All you need from Gorgonmilk & TSR: http://gorgonmilk.blogspot.com/2013/05/ia-free-lovecraftian-supplement-ocrd.html

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't like link only answers here. Could you discuss the content of that site such that when the blog decays, the content is still preserved?

Comment: Rather than being a bibliography of appearances, this is a PDF compilation of scans of the appearances themselves (*Dragon* articles and *Deities & Demigods* pages), reproduced apparently without permission or license. Summarising the table of contents would be a good answer, but linking to the PDF has piracy issues. I'm unsure whether this post should be left or deleted.